# `extern template` member functions

Tags: c++, templates, extern

I am working on a `template` function in a `class`:

```
class Data {
public:
    template <typename T>
    std::byte* serialize(const T& object) { /* serialize */ }
};
```

and I noticed that `Data::serialize<Object>` is instantiated in *every* compilation unit. For `class`es I could do, e.g.

```
extern template class Class<Object>;
```

in the header file and place

```
template class Class<Object>
```

to instantiate the `Class<Object>` only once and let the linker resolves the issue. Is there a way I do similar thing for functions and member functions?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Multiple instantiated methods are discarded on a linking stage.

Comment: Presumably he wants a faster compilation stage

Comment: @273K As @Mooing Duck said, my project takes about 20 minutes to build from scratch, and plenty of time was spent instantiating the same `Class<Object>` in different source files. By using `extern template` trick on classes, I could save about 3 minutes. I am trying to save more time by `extern template` some member functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works exactly the same.

Explicit instantiation declaration in the header:

```
extern template std::byte* Data::serialize<Object>(const Object&);
```

And explicit instantiation definition in one translation unit:

```
template std::byte* Data::serialize<Object>(const Object&);
```

(`<Object>` is optional because it can be deduced from the `const Object&` parameter.)

---

However, consider that while this may reduce compilation time, it can also negatively affect compiler optimizations, because you make it harder to inline the function (at least without link-time optimization). The resulting binary will contain only one definition of the function template specialization anyway, whether you use explicit instantiation or not.

Comment: `extern template` can still be inlined (you seem to be confusing it with a declaration for a specialization, `template<> std::byte* Data::serialize<>(const Object&);`)

Comment: @Artyer The explicit instantiation declaration should prevent implicit instantiation. While I agree that the compiler still has all the information and would be allowed to inline such a call, I guess that would be contrary to the purpose of the explicit instantiation declaration to not instantiate the function as a matter of saving compilation time, wouldn't it? Honestly, I haven't tested what compilers do though.

Comment: an explicit instantiation is still an instantiation, so the compiler has access to the definition. The main use is to shrink object file size (which improves link time since there is less code read). It should be inlined like any other template. Here is clang and gcc inlining a small extern template: https://godbolt.org/z/45norTzf9

Comment: @Artyer Yes, I see that the compilers do really behave like that. But the point of the `extern` explicit instantiation declaration should be to _not_ do the implicit instantiation in this translation unit. Otherwise there would be no point to it. Only the explicit instantiation _definition_ should cause the instantiation of the definition in the single translation unit where it appears. Actually I am bit suprised by this behavior.

Comment: @Artyer In fact I think this is a bug in both GCC and Clang. The note in https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#5 specifically mentions that `inline` functions are exempted from this behavior of the explicit instantiation declaration (see https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#1.1), but only _functions_, not _function templates_, which are defined inside a class are automatically `inline` (https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct#1). The following shouldn't fail to compile, because the explicit instantiation definition in a different compilation unit may have a complete `A`: https://godbolt.org/z/e8cjc18bc

Comment: I seems like I was mistaken about explicit instantiations of non-inline functions. However it looks like the member function is implicitly `inline` (or at least gcc/msvc think so: https://godbolt.org/z/ba1WrMbr9). And the wording is that the function `B::f<int>` is implicitly inline, because of course a function template can't be because it's not a function. See also: Use of the phrase ["non-template member function"](https://wg21.link/class#copy.assign-1.sentence-1) and ["non-template function"](https://wg21.link/temp#constr.order-2.1) which was not used here

Comment: @user17732522 I think this can be compensated by using some `#define` preprocessor, e.g. `#ifndef RELEASE_BUILD` `extern template xxx` `#endif`

Comment: @xis If you only want to speed up your debug builds, sure. But I am not sure that the benefit will be all that great usually. You still need to recompile all translation unit that depend on the header with the template definition when it is changed either way, whether you have the explicit instantiation declaration or not. (As you can see above compilers still may be doing inlining with it.) You don't save on dependencies if you go that way, only on the instantiation time.

Comment: @Artyer It seems to me that the standard is inconsistent on the use of "_function_", "_function template_" and "_function template specialization_" contrasted with "_non-template function_". I am really not sure which meaning is meant in class.mfct. The template itself can be declared with `inline`, it would mean that each _function template specialization_ (which is a _function_ (?)) is `inline`. I don't know. I think this is also the only actual behavior difference between a template marked `inline` and one not marked `inline` that I am aware of.